# Получить уникальные элементы нескольких коллекций с помощью LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Использую `Entity Framework`подход `Data Base First`. Получаю сгенерированные классы подобного типа:

```
public partial class Entry
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public partial class Entry2
{
    public Entry2()
    {
        this.Enrties = new HashSet<Entry>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<Entry> Enrties {get; set;}
}
```

Имеется необходимость получить уникальные элементы из сложной струтуры, содержащей коллекцию, внутри каждого элемента которой есть еще коллекция, а именно, опираясь на исходный код, приведенный в примере и имея исходные данные в виде коллекции:

```
// list - содержит коллекцию элементов Entry2, внутри каждого из которых коллекция Entry 
List<Entry2> list;
```

Как получить все не повторяющиеся элементы типа `Entry`, содержащиеся в коллекции переменной `list`?

Comment: А так пробовали: `@Ваша Entry2@.Enrties.Distinct().ToList()`? [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) Также можно с помощью `Where("Ваше условие")` [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) Хотя, судя по правке Вам нужен [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534631(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Denis Bubnov, Видимо я не совсем ясно сформулировал проблему.
Есть коллекция Entry2, нужно выбрать все содержащиеся в ней Entry.

Comment: Ааааа... теперь понял) сейчас напишу как

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно немного дополнить Ваш класс `Entry` интерфейсом `IEquatable`:

```
public partial class Entry : IEquatable<Entry>
{            
    public bool Equals(Entry other)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null))
            return false;

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        return Id.Equals(other.Id) && Name.Equals(other.Name);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hashProductName = Name == null ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode();
        int hashProductCode = Id.GetHashCode();
        return hashProductName ^ hashProductCode;
    }
}
```

После этого, вот такой код:

```
// для демонстрации заполним коллекции
List<Entry2> lst = new List<Entry2>()
{
    new Entry2()
    {
        Enrties =
            new List<Entry>()
            {
                new Entry() {Id = 1, Name = "1"},
                new Entry() {Id = 2, Name = "2"},
                new Entry() {Id = 3, Name = "3"}
            }
    },
    new Entry2()
    {
        Enrties =
            new List<Entry>()
            {
                new Entry() {Id = 3, Name = "3"},
                new Entry() {Id = 4, Name = "4"},
                new Entry() {Id = 5, Name = "5"}
            }
    },
    new Entry2()
    {
        Enrties =
            new List<Entry>()
            {
                new Entry() {Id = 5, Name = "5"},
                new Entry() {Id = 6, Name = "6"},
                new Entry() {Id = 7, Name = "7"}
            }
    },
};

var distinct = lst.SelectMany(x => x.Enrties).Distinct().ToList(); // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

В рузультате, в переменной `distinct` будут только уникальные.

Немного пояснений про `SelectMany`:

> [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534631(v=vs.110).aspx) - проецирует каждый элемент последовательности в
>   `IEnumerable<T>`, объединяет результирующие последовательности в одну и
>   вызывает функцию селектора результата для каждого элемента этой
>   последовательности.

Немного пояснений про `Distinct`:

> [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) - возвращает различающиеся элементы последовательности,
>   используя для сравнения значений компаратор проверки на равенство по
>   умолчанию.

Наследовали `IEquatable` и реализовали методы `Equals` и `GetHashCode` для того, чтобы `Distinct` сравнивал *по нашим правилам*, а не по умолчанию.

Comment: Беда в том, что у меня data base first, то есть сущности сгенерированы на основе таблиц базы данных, править их не разумно.
Но, за подсказку про `SelectMany` спасибо!

Comment: @xlmax, так ведь можно  использовать `partial class` не так ли?

Comment: @xlmax, Вам `EF` генерирует не `partial class`?

Comment: точно! Я и не думал в этом направлении. 
Спасибо!

Comment: в моем случае переопределять GetHashCode не нужно, так как `Entity Framework` генерирует SQL типа `SELECT DISTINCT` ...

Comment: @xlmax, спасибо за дополнение, буду знать :-) `DB First` - давно пользовался, предпочитаю `Code First`, немного подзабыл. А вообще просто на автомате переопределил. Я своему коду доверяю больше, чем автоматически сгенерированному )))